# import multiple components into a single line (Atomic Design + Vue.JS)

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, vue-component, atomic-design

I am developing a project with Vue.js and would like to apply atomic design methodology, but I would like to import the components in a clustered and smarter way

currently

```
import GridLayout from '@/components/bosons/GridLayout.vue'
import LocalStorage from '@/components/bosons/LocalStorage.vue'

import ButtonStyled from '@/components/atoms/ButtonStyled.vue'
import TextLead from '@/components/atoms/TextLead.vue'
import InputSearch from '@/components/atoms/InputSearch.vue'

import SearchForm from '@/components/molecules/SearchForm.vue'
```

how I wish

```
import {
    GridLayout,
    LocalStorage
} from '@/components/bosons'

import {
    ButtonStyled,
    TextLead,
    InputSearch
} from '@/components/atoms'

import {
    SearchForm
} from '@/components/molecules'
```

Sulution?
I thought in on putting an index.js inside folders

```
/bosons/index.js
```

```
/atoms/index.js
```

```
/molecules/index.js
```

and index.js would import all components and export, so it would be something like

```
import ButtonStyled from './ButtonStyled.vue'

export default {
  ButtonStyled
}
```

or

```
export { default as ButtonStyled } from './ButtonStyled.vue'
```

works fine, but in this way is still static, every time you create a new component, need to add it index.js, each time you delete a component, you also need to delete it from index.js

I need to import all components of the folder dynamically

the closer I got was that,

```
const req = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/)

const modules = {}

req.keys().forEach(fileName => {
  const componentName = fileName.replace(/^.+\/([^/]+)\.vue/, '$1')
  modules[componentName] = req(fileName).default
})

export const { ButtonStyled, TextLead } = modules
```

but I'm still defining the export variable names statically, I need to define dynamics based on the components inside the folder

NOTE: I can not use

```
export default modules
```

if I use the above code snippet I will not be able to import the way I need it, which is:

```
import { ButtonStyled } from "@/components/atoms"
```

Comment: Try tagging what javascript bundler you use, (I think Webpack is the default) because what you want to do can probably be accomplished in the bundler config.

Comment: What do you mean by this? `but is not feasible, every component created or deleted the index.js needs to be changed` - what do you mean by 'changed'? I just tested this with the `index.js` solution, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @MattOestreich 
this way I'm importing statically, so with every created component I have to add it in index.js, if I delete a component, also need to delete from index.js, I need index.js to import all the components inside of the folder dynamically, sorry for my bad english

Comment: So you want to auto import every single Vue file in your project in one swipe, regardless which directory they live in? I definitely don't recommend doing this, but why would you want to do this in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a Plugin Webpack, a library that is perfect for those who work with the methodology of `Atomic Design`, basically it makes `exports named` from a directory, maybe this helps other people

### [Weback Plugin - named-exports](https://github.com/yungsilva19/named-exports)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that imports **all** components in a folder **dynamically** although the import statement is **two** instead of **one** line.

Another drawback of this solution is that you would have to import the **entire** components folder every time, because the destructuring happens in the second line. This might lead to performance issues if you do not actually need **all** the components.

---

### Step 1

I also used index files in the component folder so e.g. in your bosons folder, add an index.js file with the following content:

```
const req = require.context(".", false, /\.vue$/);

const components = {};

req.keys().forEach(fileName => {
  if (fileName === "./index.js") return;
  const componentName = fileName.replace(/(\.\/|\.vue)/g, "");
  components[componentName] = req(fileName).default;
});

export default components;
```

This adds the .vue files to the components object that you can then export. It excludes the index.js file (itself).

---

### Step2

In your file where you want to import the boson components:

```
import bosons from "@/components/bosons";
const { GridLayout, LocalStorage } = bosons;
```

This imports the components and saves them in variables so you can use them.

---

Note that **in my solution** you **cannot** do

```
import { GridLayout, LocalStorage } from "@/components/bosons";
```

because the import {component} syntax looks like destructuring but isn't. It refers to the exports that look like "export const" but this is an "export default" export.

Comment: I updated my question with as close as I got to the solution, take a look please and if I can help

Comment: I cannot think of how it could be done since you cannot do dynamic "export const" in  javascript as far as I know. As Matt mentioned, what you want to do is quite unusual so it might be a good idea to think about different approaches and if it is really necessary to import all the components like this. If you really, really, really need to do it like this, you could write a script outside your vue app that changes the code itself.